# Customisation of IKM in order to change the I$ name based Upon target table Alias

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I am looking for the solution where I can customise the IKM in order to get the I$ table name as I$_table_alias where table_alias is Target Table Alias.

Need to customise the IKM step:

```
create table <%=odiRef.getTable("L", "INT_NAME", "W")%>
(
    <%=odiRef.getColList("", "[COL_NAME]\t[DEST_WRI_DT] NULL", ",\n\t", "", "")%>
    ,IND_UPDATE     char(1)
)
<%=odiRef.getOption("FLOW_TABLE_OPTIONS")%>
```

Solution which cannot be followed: I$_Session_number. This solution we are already aware about.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty simple:

- duplicate the IKM that you want to modify;
- open the duplicated IKM and modify the step/steps;
- modify the maps by changing actual IKM with the duplicated one.

Good luck!